# Swift: Extend Sequence where Iterator.Element is a Generic Type

Tags: swift, generics, swift3, sequence, where-clause

I'm using Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

I'm trying to write an extension function for `Sequence`, but only if the element type is of `MyGenericClass<Value>`. Below is a non-extension function that shows the functionality I want:

```
public class MyGenericClass<Value> {
    public func generateValue() -> Value { ... }
}

public func myFunction<Value>(_ array: Array<MyGenericClass<Value>>) -> [Value] {
    return array.map { generic in generic.generateValue() }
}
```

I've tried the following:

```
extension Sequence {
    public func myFunction<Value>() -> [Value] where Iterator.Element: MyGenericClass<Value> {
        return map { generic in generic.generateValue() }
    }
}
```

But it gives me the error: `Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> _' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'` for the map closure. I'm guessing because the compiler isn't actually inferring the element type from the where clause constraint in the body of the function?

Comment: Xcode 8 is outdated. Your code compiles in the (current) Xcode 9.4.1

Comment: Thanks, had to update from OS 10.11 but it works now.